# php access network path under windows

Tags: php, networking, path, dir

within PHP (XAMPP) installed on a Windows XP Computer Im trying to read a dir which exists on a local network server. Im using `is_dir()` to check whether it is a dir that I can read.

In Windows Explorer I type `\\\server\dir` and that dir is being shown.
When I map a network drive a can access it with `z:\dir` as well.

In PHP I have that script:

```
<?php if( is_dir($dir){ echo 'success' } ) ?>
```

For `$dir` I tried:

- `/server/dir`
- `//server/dir`
- `\server\dir`
- `\\server\dir`
- `\\\\server\\dir`

and

- `z:\dir`
- `z:\\dir`
- `z:/dir`
- `z://dir`

But I never get success?
Any idea? 
thx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved it by changing some stuff in the registry of the server as explained in the last answer of this discussion:

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=25805

Thanks to VolkerK and Gumbo anyway!
I love stackoverflow and their great people who help you so incredibly fast!!

EDIT (taken from php.net):

> The service has limited access to network resources, such as shares
>   and pipes, because it has no credentials and must connect using a null
>   session. The following registry key contains the NullSessionPipes and
>   NullSessionShares values, which are used to specify the pipes and
>   shares to which null sessions may connect:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
>   Alternatively, you could add the REG_DWORD value
>   RestrictNullSessAccess to the key and set it to 0 to allow all null
>   sessions to access all pipes and shares created on that machine.`

add RestrictNullSessAccess=0 to your registery.

Comment: This is true for Windows Server 2003. For Windows XP ensure the Local Security Policy settings "Network access: Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users" is set to Enabled.

Comment: What would some of that stuff be?  The link to php.net wasn't very helpful.  Can you consolidate your solution here?

Comment: What if we can't touch the server. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 9):

You probably let xampp install apache as service and run the php scripts trough this apache. And the apache service (running as [localsystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684190(VS.85).aspx)) is not allowed to access the network the way your user account is.

> A service that runs in the context of the LocalSystem account inherits the security context of the SCM. The user SID is created from the SECURITY_LOCAL_SYSTEM_RID value. *The account is not associated with any logged-on user account*.
> This has several implications:
> ...
>    * *The service presents the computer's credentials to remote servers*.
> ...

You can test this by starting the apache as console application (apache_start.bat in the xampp directory should do that) and run the script again. You can use both forward and backward slashes in the unc path. I'd suggest using //server/share since php doesn't care about / in string literals.

```
<?php
$uncpath = '//server/dir';
$dh = opendir($uncpath);
echo "<pre>\n";
var_dump($dh, error_get_last());
echo  "\n</pre>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the `file:` URI scheme:

```
file://server/dir
file:///Z:/dir
```

The begin is always `file://`. The next path segment is the server. If it’s on your local machine, leave it blank (see second example). See also [File URIs in Windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows.aspx).

Comment: thanks for ur answer, gumbo!
Unfortunately both solutions didn't work.
is_dir() alsways returns false.

PS: on a local dir (in example c:/dir) it returns true!

Comment: Did you try that path in your Windows Explorer? It should work there too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know this is an old post, but I still found it, and if anyone else does...
On Windows, with newer servers, verify the SMB is installed and enabled on the target machine.