# PHP is_dir() not working for windows network

Tags: php, windows, network-programming

My PHP code looks like this:

```
$dirpath = "\\\\172.16.111.91\\Data";
$dircheck = is_dir($dirpath);
if ($dircheck) {
    echo "Found";
} else {
    echo "Not Found";
}
```

If $dirpath is something like "C:/", it works fine, but I've been giving it the UNC path to a remote directory and suddenly it can't find anything.

I've tried `exec("NET USE $dirpath $password /USER:$user");` and that doesn't help.

I'm running this on Windows Server 2012 R2, PHP is v5.3, and IIS 8.5.  I think this has something to do with IIS's authentication but for the life of me I just can't figure this one out.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153824/php-access-network-path-under-windows

Comment: If you look to the right you will see several questions with exactly the same issue

Comment: I've tried looking at those and still nothing.  Unfortunately I wasn't able to fix this problem but I was able to find a suitable work-around for what I was doing!