# PHP Read or Copy File from a Network Drive (Window)

Tags: php, pdf, iis, networking, mount

I have a window drive mounted as

```
\\192.168.0.168\
```

It is mounted as Z drive

There this file in folder DOC,MYFOLDER,FILE1.PDF that I wanna readfile() or copy out through php (I will use it to copy other file also)

However I also tried stuffs like

```
$file_path = "\\192.168.0.168\DOC\MYFOLDER\FILE1.pdf";
$filesize = ($file_path); 

echo "FILE SIZE IS $filesize";
```

it return no value, just FILE SIZE IS

How do I access my Z drive or the 192.168.0.168\DOC\MYFOLDER\FILE1.pdf as I wanna share this Network drive file to my IIS Web Server so user can download the PDF through my web server.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

The backslash `\` is the [escape character](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php), it needs to be escaped:

```
$file_path = "\\\\192.168.0.168\\DOC\\MYFOLDER\\FILE1.pdf";
```

Please note that PHP does not support Windows network authentication. You may be able to [hack your way through](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1155685/1446005), but I would rather mount the network location as a network drive.

Comment: @RandomSeedI am having the same problem, I mounted my drive as Z, but it was not working I tried like Z:, Z:/, Z:\\, nothing is working, I checked the permission, I have only full control on that drive, not the system account or any other account