# How to download a file off a network drive?

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

As the title says. How can i download a file off a network drive? I currently have this, it opens the file in my Internet Explorer browser but it's supposed to download it. (Or give the option to open or download).
$search is the input given by the user.

```
<a type="button" class="UitslagKnop" href="file:\\\\domain\map\map\map\map\<?php echo $search; echo '_REV_'; echo $Revlv2; echo '_uitslag';?>.dxf" download><span>Uitslag</span></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `file:\\` in the `href` of the link. Testing your code locally doesn't initiate the download like you're attempting, but removing that prefix in the `href` does. Simply use:

```
<... href="\domain\map\map\map\map\<?php echo $search.'_REV_'.$Rev1v2.'_uitslag';?>.dxf" ...>
```

Comment: The code you are sending works if i have the files stored in the sitemap. But doesn't work when i try to access a network drive.

Comment: @MaxTheuws Ahh, my apologies, try this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020583/php-read-or-copy-file-from-a-network-drive-window