# How do I open a UNC path from my PHP file to acess another workstation's C: drive from my computer on the same network?

Tags: php, unc

I am currently improving a intranet site that runs on PHP. In it I have a table of UNC paths that are all on the same network.

eg: \mypc\c$

I have this page coded so that these UNC paths are hyperlinked so it redirects to another PHP file(Test.php). In this PHP file, I want to open a UNC path so I can access another Workstation's C: Drive, and access its folders.

```
$pcname = explode("\r", file_get_contents("PCNAMES2.txt"));
foreach($pcname as $pc) {
    echo "\\".$pc."\c$";
}
```

Instead of echoing the UNC path, I want it to open it.
PCNAMES2.txt is a text file that has the names of the workstations.

Currently, all I want is the function and the format to open a single UNC path when the hyperlink is clicked.

Thank you so much in advance. I will try and do the rest(if I can, as I am relatively new to PHP).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php access network path under windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153824/php-access-network-path-under-windows)

Comment: Do all those computers actually share their full C:-drives? If not, you can't access them either way.

Comment: yes, @Magnus, they do.